# Returning a different type than the parameter

Tags: java

This is hw and I am really stuck on how to get my code to return what I want it to return. I am trying to return a String value with a given index value. I thought all I had to do was return the string value at the given index but I am not getting the right answer.

```
    public void add(String candidate){
    if (candidate.equals(null)){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    String[] contenders = new String[candidates.length+1];

    // copy the array manually because I'm restricted from ArrayLists
    for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++){
        contenders[i] = this.candidates[i];
    }
    this.candidate = candidate;
    contenders[contenders.length-1] = this.candidate;
    this.candidates = new String [contenders.length];
```

After adding values to a newly constructed array the tester wants to get the string value at a given index

```
    public String get(int index){
    if (index < 0 || index > candidates.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Your argument was not within bounds.");
    }
    for (int i = index; i < candidate.length(); i++){
        candidate = candidates[index];
    }
    return candidate;
```

I have been working on it and I finally was able to have candidate stop pointing to null it is giving the wrong value for the given index so for example I want 'X' at candidate[3] but I am getting 'Y' because that is the last value that candidate keeps. I have tried just returning candidates[index] but then it tells me that the value at that index is null. As I have gone through the debugger it appears that my original array is not being copied over properly but I am not sure what I should try next. Thanks in advance.

This is my constructor:

```
public CandidateList(){
    candidates = new String[0];
}

public CandidateList(String[] candidates){
    this.candidates = new String[candidates.length];
    CandidateList candidateList = new CandidateList();
```

Comment: you've got bigger problems .. code is messy and a bit pointless

Comment: Uh... what? Your code will always return the last value in the array. Why do you need a for loop? You're looping until `i < candidate.length()` is false, which is the last element in the array.

Comment: How are you calling the get(index). Also what do you mean by original array not being copied properly? What is copied, what is not??

Comment: Could you post you entire code or is it too big?

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand your code: your variables' names are very similar and as I understand you have candidate both as a procedure parameter and as a member variable. The wording of the question is also very vague. Anyway, look at the last line of the first code block: you assign an uninitialized block to this.candidates, and look at the second block: you take the return value from this uninitialized block. By the way are you talking of multiple strings, or one string that has multiple characters?

Comment: @1blustone is not the last element in the array, is always the element at the index position..he is not using the 'i' var

Comment: @deathyr true. In that case the for loop is truly useless. OP is setting the value to the same thing multiple times.

Comment: Its too big to post everything and I am passing half of the junit tests and was trying to figure out where my logic was off. with some of the other tests. I'm not really looking for a direct answer I'm more interested in figuring out the logic. And what my code represents is my level of understanding of what is being asked of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that can be improved in your code, let me add some comments

```
    public void add(String candidate){
    //if candidate is actually null you are calling null.equals
    //which means this will always result in a NullPointerException
    //you can remove this if if you want
    if (candidate.equals(null)){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    ...

    //think about what you are doing here, 
    //you are setting this.candidates to a new empty array 
    //(is big contenders.length, but still empty) 
    this.candidates = new String [contenders.length];
```

Second part:

```
    public String get(int index){
    //you are missing an '=' in index >= candidates.length
    if (index < 0 || index > candidates.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Your argument was not within bounds.");
    }
    //this for loop is wrong, you are changing 'i' but never use it.. 
    //just return candidates[index] like you said before. 
    //It was probably null because of the error above
    for (int i = index; i < candidate.length(); i++){
        candidate = candidates[index];
    }
    return candidate;
```

A note on the RuntimeException(RE): if you catch a NullPointerException (NPE) and throw a RE you are actually losing information (since NPE is a more specific error rather than RE). If you want to catch/throw put at least a significant message like "candidate cannot be null"

Let's now analyze the constructor:

```
public CandidateList(){
    candidates = new String[0];
}

public CandidateList(String[] candidates){

    // you are doing the same error as above here:
    // when you do this you create an EMPTY list of size candidates.lenght
    // correct code is this.candidates = candidates
    this.candidates = new String[candidates.length];

    // this is not necessary, constructors don't need to return anything, 
    //here you are just creating a new instance that will not be used anywhere
    CandidateList candidateList = new CandidateList();
```

Constructors create objects, they don't return data. I suggest you to take a look at this question [Does a Java constructor return the Object reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625978/does-a-java-constructor-return-the-object-reference) and in general read a bit more about constructors

Comment: I am new to Java and its more than obvious I'm not following the flow of control. So in my junit tests one of the test called my constructor and gives it a string array. Then the test uses the add method to tack on a new value to the end of the array. The get method should then return the single string value at the index where the new candidate was placed. So I am wondering if the argument that is sent to the constructor is not being sent to the String [].

Comment: Thank you for walking though the process rather than focusing on how messy my code is

Comment: No worries, everybody needs to start somewhere :) Can you post your constructor too? If your junit is failing would be helpful to also have that code. Otherwise please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I posted my constructor

Comment: Awesome. Ok so I just need the first expression and the second one I don't need to create a new object?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just this.candidates = candidates

Comment: I tested my code again and it is saying that still some of the elements in my array are null. Its like it goes through the add method but never keeps the values which makes the get method to point to null.

Comment: did you change the last line in add() to be     this.candidates = contenders?

Comment: I did and it is still giving null.

Comment: Try to insert debugging statements like this 

     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(candidates));

at the beginning and end of your add() method and see if you can figure out what is wrong. You will need to import java.util.Arrays;